# Loaded Configuration File: (none) -> How to correct this?? (PHP)

Tags: php, windows, apache

I`m using PHP on Windows since two weeks. Until now i don´t had any problems what so ever. But now i need to change something in my "php.ini" and i can´t do it because no file is loaded as a configuration file.

If I´m writing "php --ini" in my cmd i get the following answer.

```
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
    Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
    Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
    Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I have already read some other questions regarding this topic but all the answers didn´t work for me. I have a directory "c:/php" with a php.ini file. I tried to copy it to "c:/windows" and restarted apache but nothing changed at all.

I really hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to use PHP on windows?

Comment: At least it would be beneficial.

Comment: How did you install PHP? Xampp? MAMP? Wamp? Makes a difference to where the PHP config file should be located.